# What is the correct way of creating constants, getting constants and calling a method from multiple classes in OOP in Kotlin for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, oop, kotlin, constants

What is the correct way of creating constants, creating LocalTime objects based on these constants and calling these objects and a method from multiple classes in OOP in Kotlin for Android?

I have 4 fragments. Each fragment checks whether the current time is between two specified times (constants).

Are constants supposed to go in their own class, if I call them from multiple classes?
Do I need a separate class to create the LocalTime objects and for the method that I call from multiple classes?

My current constants class looks like this:

```
package ...

// Pinging
const val PING_INTERVAL_IN_MS: Long = 60000 //1 minute

// Screen navigation
const val SCREEN_NAV_IN_MS: Long = 10000 //10 minutes

// Testing times
const val TEST_START_HOUR = 9
const val TEST_START_MINUTE = 0
const val TEST_END_HOUR = 10
const val TEST_END_MINUTE = 0
    // Testing flash interval
    const val TEST_TIMER_FLASH_IN_MS: Long = 1000

// Break times
// Break 1
const val BREAK1_START_HOUR = 10
const val BREAK1_START_MINUTE = 15
const val BREAK1_END_HOUR = 10
const val BREAK1_END_MINUTE = 30
// Break 2
const val BREAK2_START_HOUR = 12
const val BREAK2_START_MINUTE = 30
const val BREAK2_END_HOUR = 13
const val BREAK2_END_MINUTE = 0
// Break 3
const val BREAK3_START_HOUR = 15
const val BREAK3_START_MINUTE = 30
const val BREAK3_END_HOUR = 16
const val BREAK3_END_MINUTE = 0
```

I currently have a Utils class, in which I have my methods that each fragment calls. Is this good practice in OOP? My Utils class looks like the following:

```
object Utils {
    val testStartTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(TEST_START_HOUR, TEST_START_MINUTE)
    val testEndTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(TEST_END_HOUR, TEST_END_MINUTE)
    val break1StartTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(BREAK1_START_HOUR, BREAK1_START_MINUTE)
    val break1EndTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(BREAK1_END_HOUR, BREAK1_END_MINUTE)
    val break2StartTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(BREAK2_START_HOUR, BREAK2_START_MINUTE)
    val break2EndTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(BREAK2_END_HOUR, BREAK2_END_MINUTE)
    val break3StartTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(BREAK3_START_HOUR, BREAK3_START_MINUTE)
    val break3EndTime: LocalTime = LocalTime.of(BREAK3_END_HOUR, BREAK3_END_MINUTE)

    /**
     * Check if currentTime is a break
     *
     * @return Type of break
     * 0 = testen
     * 1 = break 1
     * 2 = break 2
     * 3 = break 3
     */
    fun isBreak(): Int {
        val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")), LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")))

        return if(currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(break1StartTime) && currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(break1EndTime)) {
            1
        } else if(currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(break2StartTime) && currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(break2EndTime)) {
            2
        } else if(currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(break3StartTime) && currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(break3EndTime)) {
            3
        } else {
            0
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return if time is between start and end times of 'test' or 'break'
     *
     * @return Whether time is between start and end times of 'test' or 'break'
     */
    fun checkTime(): Boolean {
        val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")), LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam")))

        //TODO: Also check if currentTime is before meetingDateTime - 1 && currentTime is after meetingDateTime + 1
        return (currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(testStartTime) && currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(testEndTime)) ||
                (currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(break1StartTime) && currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(break1EndTime)) ||
                (currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(break2StartTime) && currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(break2EndTime)) ||
                (currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isAfter(break3StartTime) && currentDateTime.toLocalTime().isBefore(break3EndTime))
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to sound like a jerk, but one shouldn't be doing any business logic in `Fragment`. Once you have a place for your domain logic, the place for constants usually crystallizes naturally.

Comment: @Agent_L Thinking about this now.. Do you recommend I 'auto navigate' my fragments from within my activity? That have all the navigation in one class, and I wouldn't need to call the methods in my Utils.kt class in every fragment.

Comment: I don't know your app and I don't understand what "auto navigate" means. My chief design goal is to isolate myself as far as possible from pesky platform peculiarities, like `Activity` or `Fragment`. Also, to separate view logic from business logic - and time checking sounds like business. So I imagine a business component first and then hook up UI to it, NOT the other way around. Basically: imagine that tomorrow you'll have to throw away all the old UI and write completely new one from scratch - if you can keep most of your code, that's a good design.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like someone deleted my comment where I explained "auto navigate", so let me explain it again. I check if the current time is between two specified times in my fragments because the app navigates automatically. It loops between 4 fragments. I have a scheduled task in my MainActivity. The scheduled task navigates to a 'standalone' fragment. When this scheduled task runs, the auto navigation in my fragment loop wants to keep going, but since the fragment isn't active, I get an error. To catch this error, I check if the current time is the same as the scheduled task's time.

Comment: Navigation is also platform details, so I try to abstract it away. Activity creates navigator implementation and saves it somewhere, so ViewModels can use it. Sounds like 1) running task should be cancelled when it's owner dies, checking for time sounds fragile. 2) I'd try to extract all this juggling logic into one object, that controls the screen switching but not being affected by their lifetime. 3) Are you sure that navigating 4 `Fragment`s is the best approach? Maybe showing and hiding `View`s would suit you better.